# Sorting ArrayList data within table

Tags: java

I have a `TreeTable` and would like to perform the sort by number and alphabetically when clicking on header.

#### Example:

- On a first click, I have to check that the column content is sorted by number
- If I click on another column that contains `String` data, I have to check that column content is sorted alphabetically.

Are there known functions that could I use?

I've used Collections for sorting number , but how do I can make the sort alphabetically ?
Collections.sor(myList) is OK for sorting by number but I would sort data alphabetically.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done via `Collections.sort(...)`. Create a copy of your list, sort it and check if they are equal.

Example:

```
List <String> copy = new ArrayList <String>(original);
Collections.sort(copy);
assertEquals(copy, original);
```

This can be done, if the elements in the list are comparable (i.e. are of type `T implements Comparable <T>`). Strings are comparable, and their default comparator sorts them alphabetically (though upper-case are always comes before lower-case)

You may also provide a `Comparator` for a more flexible sorting.

Here is a more complicated example.

```
List <String> unholyBible = new ArrayList <String>();
unholyBible.add("armageddon");
unholyBible.add("abyss");
unholyBible.add("Abaddon");
unholyBible.add("Antichrist");
Collections.sort(unholyBible);
System.out.println(unholyBible);
```

This will print us `[Abaddon, Antichrist, abyss, armageddon]`. This is because default comparation is case-sensitive. Lets fix it:

```
List <String> unholyBible = new ArrayList <String>();
unholyBible.add("armageddon");
unholyBible.add("abyss");
unholyBible.add("Abaddon");
unholyBible.add("Antichrist");
Collections.sort(unholyBible, new Comparator <String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2){
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
});
System.out.println(unholyBible);
```

This one prints `[Abaddon, abyss, Antichrist, armageddon]`.

Now you may worship Satan in strict alphabetical order.

#### See also

- [Comparator API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Frozen: I'm wrinting Junit test to verify the sort on table : getValue on column returns mean ArrayList od data and I would like to check that data is sorted alphabeticcaly

Comment: Sorry, your "first click" reference has confused me. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Frozen, it works when the content is a number but in the case where my conlumn content has : "abc",efd""abg",.. it doesn't make the sort alphabetically, this is my problem

Comment: could you develop more on using comparator, I search also in google but I don't find some precisions about sort alphabatically on ArrayList

Comment: @lola Collections.sort() dose support string sorting, because String has its own compareTo() implementment.

Comment: @lola Rangi is right, String are comparable by themseves. However, their comparation is case-sensitive. Anyway, check my answer again. I hope this example will help you to understand `Comparator` mechanics.

Comment: @Rangi and Frozen : I have used it as follow :  ArrayList<String> list = table.getList("column"); table.click();Comparator<String> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.sort(list, comparator); and this is OK but I want to compare using assertion if really the table is sorted ???

Comment: @lola : What do you meant by compare using assertion ? are you trying to write a unit-test for Collections.sort or ? please provide more information

Comment: getList("column") from table give me a list "myList" a values , after a click on table, the values are sorted  , now I would like to use assertion like : assertEqauls(Collections.sort(list, comparator),myList) how could I get the results of sort to make it comparable to myList ?

Comment: @lola : Since Collections.sort() dose not return any value. So you need a extra copy List from getList("column"), then sort it with Collections.sort() before you call assertEquals.

Comment: @lola If you'll finally look at the first example above in my answer, everything should become crystal clear. This discussion becomes absurd.

Comment: sorry Frozen if I don't explain correctly my problem, but what do you mention as solution comes after my first problem which is how to make the sort, now it is clear to me, the only problem is I need to click once on table, make a copy and compare, then click another time and make another copy=>the second copy doesn't work

Comment: I doubt we can tell you anything about why your second copy doesnt work until you'll supply us with a source of your test and information about your table (and how it's sorting is implemented), but for that you'll need to create another question, as this goes far out of this topic's bound.